# foundation 4 section vertical nav flyout menu on mouseover

Tags: menu, mouseover, zurb-foundation, flyout

I am trying to test out zurb foundation 4 css framework. If zurb's web site foundation 4 doc, it mentions foundation 4 uses sections to replace accordion, tabs and vertical nav and & nav bar of old foundation 3. But I couldn't find how to make the vertical nav on mouseover; I have to click on the title. How can I make the vertical nav a flyout menu on mouseover? Mouseover is pretty standard approach, I hope there is simple way to turn it on in foundation 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can set data-options="is_hover" on your dropdown target to enable hover.

Check this link [Add hover state support for dropdowns by setting is_hover data-options.](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/aa6035eccab10caa9c33965bea832ebab82fe0e9)

Answer (score 0):

currently

```
data-options="is_hover:true"
```

Is not support to section. You must use **custom js** to make it work.

Let's try

```
$(".section").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```